# What women are mentioned explicitly converting into Judaism without marrying a Jew?

Tags: sources-mekorot, women, conversion-to-judaism

I was trying to recall a case of a woman mentioned explicitly converting into Judaism without marrying a Jew (i.e. *in order* to marry a Jew), but couldn't; IIRC even R' Akiva's Matronita finally married him.

What are examples of female "autonomous" conversion in our sources?

Comment: Are we counting Ruth here or not?

Comment: How about Queen Hilleni in the mishna? I mean it sounds like she converted later.

Comment: Broadly -- how much do we have in our literature about women who died single?

Comment: @יהושעק IIRC Ruth is not mentioned as "converting" per se, and she did marry Boaz or at least slept with him.

Comment: So the criteria is women who converted and stayed single the rest of their lives? How is a conversion less "autonomous" if she marries years after the fact? I want to help here, I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: @יהושעק I edited to stress "who did not convert in order to marry a Jew". Many women "converted" only implicitly, after we saw them marrying Jewish men.

Comment: That's why I asked about Ruth....she converted long before Boaz came on the scene, her decision took place before she had even arrived in Beit Lechem and she was specifically told there was no one for her to marry

Comment: Basya bas pharaoh

Comment: @Chatzkel וְאֵלֶּה, בְּנֵי בִּתְיָה בַת-פַּרְעֹה, אֲשֶׁר לָקַח, מָרֶד the only time she is mentioned  by name is as the wife of someone